# creating android db table

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, debugging

I am new on android. I am trying to create a table in a db using the following code but there is some error

```
db.beginTransaction();
    try {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `book` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,`author_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,`text_b` text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;");
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.d("Maaz", "Exception 2 : SQL Exception 2 " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
```

The above code is giving me the following error

```
Failure 1 (near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error)
on 0x23c510 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `book` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,`author_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,`text_b` text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;'.
```

Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `AUTO_INCREMENT` to `AUTOINCREMENT`.

### Edit:

Try this,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    title varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    author_name varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    text_b TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: no its not. I tried it as well but not helpful .
`   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `book` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,`title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,`author_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,`text_b` text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTOINCREMENT =1 ;");
   `

Comment: You get the same syntax error? `Failure 1 (near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error)`?

Comment: It's the same as in what... you get the same exact error message but with `AUTOINCRMENT` right?

Comment: I removed the attributes `Engine` and other things which I mentioned in my answer. and that worked for me. thank you so much for your response.

Comment: That was going to be my next guess haha. Glad you figured it out. You should accept an answer to close the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

what kind of database, it makes a difference for the SQL syntax.  You should try to create the database table first in the console editor and then you can paste that syntax in your code.  It's also usually not a good idea to create tables from code with a generic execSQL.  You should use an ORM or database library or framework for this.  A continuous integration server could also create this table unless your are creating it on the client's android device.  Hibernate is nice for keeping messy SQL out of your code.

Can you tell us what kind of database?

You can also check out this article:

http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/01/creating-multiple-sqlite-database.html

Very close syntax if you are using SQLite

Comment: I created DB using wampServer, and export the `sql` file and trying to copy the code over here, but that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked at last in my case.

### Answer :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (
   _id Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   title varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   author_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   text_b TEXT NOT NULL);
```

Removing Engine, DEFAULT CHARSET worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have quotes surrounding the identifiers (I.e. `books`). Remove them.